# git: does moving tons of files in a commit affect repository size?

Tags: git

Consider a *git* repository that initially contains tons files and no directories. Now, I want to move all these files in a new directory. For this reason I perform a *commit* in which all the files are deleted from their original position and re-added in the new one.

Does this operation significantly increase the size of my repository?

Comment: A moved file doesn't use space in a commit (apart from its new name/location that replaces the old name/location.) The file's content, if not modified, already exists in the repo and it's not added again.

Answer (score 1):

No. Git stores the actual file contents separate from the directory structure, and moving a file does not cause it to be duplicated. Git will store new directory trees to match the new directory structure. These contain only the names of the files and a reference to the data they contain, so the change in repo size should be hardly noticable.

See [10.2 Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/) for more detailed information about Git's object storage model.

Comment: Moving files within a repository (as a rename) can cause your `.git` directory to increase significantly in size, though, at least temporarily. Use `git gc` to clean up and regain some free space. Although, as far as I can tell, even without `git gc`, pushing to the remote doesn't increase the remote size.